# SVG animate beginElement() does not work with endElement()

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to make SVG animation shows up on scroll when it's in the viewport. However, I found that my code doesn't work when I use `beginElement()` and `endElement()`.

```js
var svgLocation = document.getElementById("mysvg").getBoundingClientRect();
var offsetToTriggerAnimation = svgLocation.y + svgLocation.height;

function scrollAnimTriggerCheck(evt)
{
  var viewBottom = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
  if (viewBottom > offsetToTriggerAnimation) {
    document.getElementById("anime").beginElement();
  }else{
    document.getElementById("anime").endElement();
  }
}
document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollAnimTriggerCheck);
```

```css
.project img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
.showcase_wrap{
  max-width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
.project{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase_wrap">
  <div class="project">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543363951-d1feb17b7338?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="project_bg">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M374.3,204.3c17.5,97.9-96.3,127.9-188.5,165.3C91.7,407.7,23.9,292.8,23.9,193.4c0-135.5,91.1-174,190.5-170.2C281.9,25.8,362.6,138.5,374.3,204.3Z" fill="#e14444">
        <animate
          id="anime"
          dur="2s"
          begin="indefinite"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          attributeName="d"
          values="M374.3,204.3c17.5,97.9-96.3,127.9-188.5,165.3C91.7,407.7,23.9,292.8,23.9,193.4c0-135.5,91.1-174,190.5-170.2C281.9,25.8,362.6,138.5,374.3,204.3Z;M374.3,214.3c17.5,97.9-38.8,105.4-130.9,142.8C149.3,395.2,26.7,268.3,26.7,168.8c0-135.5,111.7-119,211-115.2C305.3,56.2,362.6,148.5,374.3,214.3Z;M374.3,204.3c17.5,97.9-96.3,127.9-188.5,165.3C91.7,407.7,23.9,292.8,23.9,193.4c0-135.5,91.1-174,190.5-170.2C281.9,25.8,362.6,138.5,374.3,204.3Z;" />
      </path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the entire code here too.
https://codepen.io/ohsik/pen/bOVvmr

Comment: That's [a known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=241742) in Chrome, closed as wont-fix because they once intended to deprecate SMIL but now that they're back in, might worth reopening it.

Answer (score 0):

This was an old bug on Chrome where they didn't ignored correctly calls to *endElement()*, when the animate element was inactive.

Here is the [crbug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=241742#c19), and the fix is active on latest chrome v73.